# R - how to join two tables based on proportion

Tags: r

I have two dataframes a and b, and would like to join or "allocate" the rows in b to the rows in a, proportionally based on a column in a.

For example:

```
a = data_frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"), n = c(1000, 500, 300, 200))
a = a %>% mutate(proportion = n / sum(n))

b = data_frame(record = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))

c = data_frame(record = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
               color = c("red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "orange"),
               proportion = c(".5", ".5", ".5", ".5", ".5", ".25", ".25", ".25", ".15", ".1"))
```

For example, I want the resulting data.frame, c, to contain all each "record" from b joined with "color", based on the proportion of each color in a.

Hopefully my example is clear, but hoping it could work with uneven numbers, and okay if a given record from a is not matched to any record in b based on a low probability.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any connection between the value in `record` and the `color` that gets assigned to it? Do you just want there to be a 50% chance of red being assigned, a 25% chance of blue being assigned etc.?

Comment: Is the size of b determined of can we adapt as long as it is bigger than the size of a? Is b size fixed?

Comment: Is this example you would need 5 red, 2.5  blue, 1.5 green, 1 orange. Do you pick 3 blue or 2 green? How did you decide to go for 3 blue? We gonna need a lot more rules

Comment: @divibisan, no connection between the values, yes to what you described

Comment: @MaxFt yes, ideally we would need 5 red, 2.5 blue, etc., although what I'm looking for is for each record from b to just be assigned a color, based on that color's probability.  So, in my example I picked 3 blue because the probability of blue is .25, but if I were to run it again maybe I would get 0 blue just by chance.

Comment: And to clarify, I'm looking for a solution that works for an arbitrary number of rows of data.frames a and b

Comment: You wanna pick randomly only for blue and green because they are equally far from they floor part ? I mean what if you need 2.6 blue and 2.5 green? Do you always pick blue?  Also should the 5 red be also  radom?

Comment: In other words do you want the closest deterministic distribution (proportion wise) so that there is only randomness when two colors have the proportion and an extra row needs to be assigned. Or a pure random sample based or your proportion?

Comment: @MaxFt, the latter

Comment: Oh ok in that case you got the answer below now. You do not even need to compute the proportion

Comment: @dreww2 Actually the expected result data.frame `c` had values assigned in order of `proportion` which confused us a bit. I thought you wanted rows from `b` in order of proportion.

Comment: I dont think `and okay if a single record from b is not matched to a based on a low probability.` from question has still got answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
set.seed(1)
a %>%
   sample_n(size = nrow(b), replace = TRUE, weight = proportion) %>%
   bind_cols(b)

#output:
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   color      n proportion record
   <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr> 
 1 red    1000.      0.500 a     
 2 red    1000.      0.500 b     
 3 blue    500.      0.250 c     
 4 orange  200.      0.100 d     
 5 red    1000.      0.500 e     
 6 green   300.      0.150 f     
 7 orange  200.      0.100 g     
 8 blue    500.      0.250 h     
 9 blue    500.      0.250 i     
10 red    1000.      0.500 j
```

sample `nrow(b)` rows from `a` with replacement, with a weight equal to the proportion

Comment: This is what I did first but I think he wants the distribution to be as  deterministic as possible and to include randomness for the tricky cases

Comment: he said `maybe I would get 0 blue just by chance`, so as i understand @missuse 's answer is fine

Comment: You are right. I over complicated the problem. My first answer was right. I undeleted it ^^

Comment: Good use of `sample_n` but I dont think `and okay if a single record from b is not matched to a based on a low probability.` has been taken in our answers.

Comment: @MKR I agree your answer matches this statement, and that the dreww2 was not super clear with his demand. But in the comments he answers `the latter` which is:  `a pure random sample based on your proportion` - comments 8/9. Additionally  check 1/2 comments to this answer.

Comment: That's true that he had clarified it later. I was just wondering about the other part of question where `single record of b is not matched` is mentioned. In our solution all `b` records will be matched, Isn't it?

Comment: I find that statement unclear. if it means that some color with low probability will not be picked at all in some instances, then `sample` covers that  - `set.seed(3)` to check. If it means one row of `b` is not matched to `a` I am not sure how would the two data frames be joined if they would have different number of rows.

Comment: I meant it as one or more color(s) not being picked at all in some instances, but agree with the lack of clarity in the haste of writing the question.  I've updated it to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your data frame `a` the colors are present in the right proportion. Thus, all you need to do in `sample with replacement` from the rows of your data frame `a`:

```
library(data.table)
c=cbind(b,as.data.table(a)[sample(1:nrow(a),nrow(b),replace=TRUE),])
```

with this you do not need the proportion variable

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach with `join`. The approach is to first calculate the range of `rows` from `b` based on proportion in `a`. The join `a` with `b` on row-ranges.

```
a = data_frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"), n = c(1000, 500, 300, 200))
b = data_frame(record = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))

library(data.table)

setDT(a)
setDT(b)

a[order(-n),':='(proportion = (n/sum(n)), rowMax = round(cumsum(nrow(b)*(n/sum(n)))))]
a[,minRow := shift(rowMax, type = "lag", fill = 0)]
a[b[,rownum := .I], on=.(rowMax >= rownum, minRow < rownum)][,.(record, color, proportion)]

#result
#     record  color proportion
# 1:      a    red       0.50
# 2:      b    red       0.50
# 3:      c    red       0.50
# 4:      d    red       0.50
# 5:      e    red       0.50
# 6:      f   blue       0.25
# 7:      g   blue       0.25
# 8:      h   blue       0.25
# 9:      i  green       0.15
# 10:     j orange       0.10
```